# How to automate memory testing using Xcode9 instruments allocations

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode9, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

> Memory testing. What are the Possible automations?

- I would like to do UI automation tests and look into memory testing using xcode9 instruments. This is something that is currently hurting our product. In the app there are places where the application leaks memory causing crashes in very random locations which makes reproducible steps difficult.

> How can I create a subset of test scripts and capture where the leaks are?

I can check memory allocations and leaks manually using instruments as below -

[image]